# When I run executable from python and pass the arguements I get nothing

Tags: python, sys, matlab-compiler

Here is the link to the program that I want to use: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/ShapeSPH/ShapeDescriptor/ and I want to run at through python with the following command

```
import subprocess
args = ['C:\\Path\\ShapeDescriptor.exe', "--in", "x.ply", "--out", "x.txt" ]
subprocess.call(args, shell=True)
```

But when I run it, I get something like:

```
#QNAN0 1.#QNAN0 1.#QNAN0 -1.#IND00
```

I can run ShapeDescriptor.exe from the command prompt as:

```
ShapeDescriptor.exe --in x.ply -out x.txt
```

and get the desired x.txt file with numbers for instance:

```
0.003294 0.003386 0.003426 0.001029
```

How I could solve the problem?

Comment: `--in` and `x.ply` are actually separate arguments, for shell purposes.  Likewise `-out` and `x.txt`.  Also, is it really double-dash for in and single dash for out?

Comment: guessing slightly - split the arguments out? `args = ['C:\\Path\\ShapeDescriptor.exe', "--in", "x.ply", "-out", "x.txt" ]`. Subprocess should be able to deal with it.

Comment: @mattbornski  it is also double dash, sorry I use double dash but it didn't work

Comment: @asongtoruin it didn't work

Comment: It should be "--out" with a double-dash, too.  This may explain why @asongtoruin's attempt failed as you have not commented on it.

Comment: Is anything working for you? Say (Linux user here, no idea if this still works, but you get the idea) something along ["copy", "C:\\autoexec.bat","C:\\test.bat"]?

Comment: I think now it works, but output is something like "#QNAN0 1.#QNAN0 1.#QNAN0 -1.#IND00 why it could be the case ?"

Comment: @edyvedy13 You're being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350459/what-can-be-done-about-users-who-do-not-seem-to-understand-when-answers-should-b) please consider replaying there if want to (You don't have to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If splitting does not do the trick you may also want to provide a working directory using the cwd argument. Maybe x.txt is created in an unexpected location.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False) with the options or subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False).

The difference is that if the processes returns an error code, the check_call will get a CalledProcessError.

Another strategy is to use chdir function to change the current directory berofe executing the exe file, as follows:

*import os*

*os.chdir( 'c:\documents and settings\programs\' )*